# Search index doesn't update

Tags: search

I've needed to to add a few fields to the search index «Use this field’s values as search keywords» after quite a few entries already have been created. Now the search index doesn't seem to get updated, even if I resave an entry manually.

```
php craft resave/entries --update-search-index
```

This command is not an option since I have limited access to the hosting...

I'm looking for something similar like the clear cache options in the utilities tab. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the search index updated after you saved the field config with the search index option selected? It should have. Re-saving an entry only triggers a re-index if you've actually edited something within the entry, so if it behaved correctly and re-indexed after your field edit... nothing was changed and therefore no further re-index needed to happen.

You could try editing a field value and saving to confirm that re-indexing is happening when it should.

Comment: I feel like the search index didn't update after i saved the field config. I've just edited an entry and saved it. This seems to work and the search index got updated.
Since i can't access `php craft resave/entries --update-search-index`on the hosting, do i need to change entries manually, save the changed entry, revert the change & save it again? Or is there a better solution?
At least new entries seem to get indexed :)

Comment: What hosting platform do you use? Many have the ability to run a command via the GUI that you may be able to use.

Comment: Also - you could try editing the field again to uncheck the index. Save. Then check the index setting and save again. Pay close attention to the queue notices to see if it indexes. This would be the simplest without data loss.